# How to do "Object.defineProperty" in pure Rhino object model?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

With Rhino 17R4, we can create properties in javascript using Object.defineProperty() method.

```
public class MyGlobalObject : org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject
{
    public static org.mozilla.javascript.Script ___compiledScript = null;
    public MyGlobalObject()
    {
        org.mozilla.javascript.Context con = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();
        try
        {
            con.initStandardObjects(this);
            string strScript = "Object.defineProperty(this,\r\n 'onload', \r\n{  set : function(val){this.set_onload(val);},\r\n get : function(){return this.get_onload();}, enumerable: true, configurable: true});";

            this.defineFunctionProperties(new string[] { "set_onload", "get_onload" }, typeof(MyGlobalObject), org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.DONTENUM);
            org.mozilla.javascript.Script sc = con.compileString(strScript, "", 1, null);
            object result_onload = con.evaluateString(this, "this.onload == undefined;", "", 1, null); // make sure it is not defined.
            Console.WriteLine("onload is undefined? : {0}", result_onload);
            // Define Properties Now.
            sc.exec(con, this);


            con.evaluateString(this, "this.onload= function(){var t1 = 1;};", "", 1, null);
            object onloadobjectXYZ = con.evaluateString(this, "this.onload;", "", 1, null); // get function now.
            Console.WriteLine("Onload object : {0} is found", onloadobjectXYZ);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        org.mozilla.javascript.Context.exit();
    }
    private object __onloadFunction;
    public object get_onload()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("get_onload() called!");
        return this.__onloadFunction;
    }
    //[org.mozilla.javascript.annotations.JSSetter]
    public void set_onload(object _val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("set_onload() called!");
        this.__onloadFunction = _val;
    }

    public override string getClassName()
    {
        return "Global";
    }

}
```

How can I create FunctionObject which is identical to "onloadobjectXYZ" in pure rhino object operation (not by using script like'strScipt')? It seems that it may be able to create FunctionObject for setter and getter, but I could not find a good example. Does anyone know how to define properties?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ?? This question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: You might also put the existing Java code in the question, so that we know which (native?) object you want to equip with getters/setters.

Comment: I changed my sample to avoid confusion. What i like to do is to create  setter and getter 'onreadystatechange' property.

Answer (score 0):

defineProperty with java Method setter / getter is slightly different from object.defineProprty()

```
  this.defineProperty("onload", null, javaonloadGetMethod, javaonloadSetMethod, ScriptableObject.PERMANENT);
```

This works for me as a workaround.